# Corrections/review of a verse translation

Tags: classical-latin, translation-check, medieval-latin

I'm translating a Tennyson verse (Sir Galahad) and had it went over by a couple of folks with some corrections. I would like you guys to give it a final pass if you would be so kind. I searched and couldn't find it being asked previously.

> Meus fidelis gladius galeas virorum secat,
> Mea dura lancea certe percutit,
> Mea vis tamquam vis  decem virorum,
> Quia meus cor purus est.

Original verse:

> My good blade carves the casques of men,
> My tough lance thrusteth sure,
> My strength is as the strength of ten
> Because my heart is pure.

A more medieval Latin flavor was intended.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to the site, and very nice question!

Answer (score 5):

It's a pretty straightforward translation and is mostly correct. Just a few notes:

1. You probably also want *cassides* instead of *galeas*, since the [*cassis*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcassis1) is made of metal and the [*galea*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=galeas&la=la#lexicon) is leather.
2. The last line should be *meum...purum*, because *cor* is neuter.
3. *purum est cor meum* sounds better to me; although it breaks the symmetry, but it flows much more smoothly.
4. Likewise, *vis tamquam...* sounds off to me. I'd probably properly make it a [correlative](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dtam): *tam fortis sum quam decem viri sunt* ("I am as strong as ten men.")
5. In the second line, Latin would likely make *certe* an adjective instead of an adverb, with something like: *Mea lancea dura certaque percutit.* It's really the lance more than the cutting that is *certus* here. This is Classical, but I don't know for sure how Medieval Latin would differ.

Comment: Thank you so much cmw, this is super helpful! Would idem quod, the same as, also work instead of tamquam? I agree it does seem off.

Comment: No, *id est* wouldn't make sense at all. You could reword it still but the construction I gave is standard.

Comment: Oh, and if you find an answer helpful, remember to upvote and (if it solves the question) check mark it.

Comment: Thanks again for the help! Sadly I cannot as I lack the reputation to upvote or comment. I also was for some reason locked out of the original account. I asked a question as a guest (user10936) and when I went to finish account creation in the email it created a different account (Prime Paladin). I have no way to access the original account as it redirects me to this one, I deeply apologize and have attempted to upvote your very useful answer!

Comment: Interesting. Let me see if I can figure out how to help. Hang tight.

Comment: Nice answer! I think in your point 4 _sunt_ is optional: _tam fortis sum quam decem viri_ or even _tam fortis quam decem viri sum_ do the trick as well. Totally agree with you about word order in no. 3 (unless the verse or other reason suggests otherwise).

Comment: @PrimePaladin [Here are instructions for merging two accounts](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), which is what we recommend. It solves problems like this. We moderators can't do it ourselves, so you have to follow the instructions and then wait. Let us know if you have any questions.